# Дано предложение. Вывести буквы, которые содержатся в максимальном количестве слов

Tags: c++

Нужно вывести буквы которые содержаться в максимальном количестве слов. Строки для меня тема новая поэтому не совсем понимаю как с ними работать попытался по советам сделать(создать массив для букв с нулевыми значениями и дальше проверять слова), но пишет что недопустимо для class, хотелось бы понять что это значит и как это исправить. Также я понимаю что с реализацией кода беда, но не понимаю как лучше сделать ее. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

```
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
        int max = INT_MIN;
        string str;
        string razdel = "!?,.:;- "; //Знаки пунктуации и пробел
        cout << "Введите строку: ";
        getline(cin, str); //Вводим строку
        str += '.'; //Добавляем точку в конец строки
        string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
        int** a = new int*[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            a[i] = new int[59];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 59; ++j) {
                a[1][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        string::size_type pos = 0, k;
        string::size_type max = 0;
        k = str.find_first_of(razdel); //Ищем конец первого слова
        while (k != string::npos) { //Пока находятся слова
            string word = str.substr(pos, k - pos); //Копируем слово
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); ++j) {
                    if(str[i] == alphabet[j]){
                        a[1][j]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            k = str.find_first_of(razdel, pos); //Ищем конец следующего слова
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 59; ++j) {
                if (a[1][j] > max) {
                    max = a[1][j];
                }
            }
        }
        cout << max; //Просто хотел проверить работает ли код и правильно ли выводит
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример кода:

```
string str;
string razdel = "!?,.:;- "; //Знаки пунктуации и пробел
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
int size = alphabet.size();
int* a = new int[59]{ 0 };

cout << "Введите строку: ";
getline(cin, str); //Вводим строку
str += '.'; //Добавляем точку в конец строки

string::size_type pos = 0, k, t;
k = str.find_first_of(razdel); //Ищем конец первого слова
while (k != string::npos) { //Пока находятся слова
    int j = 0;
    //Задача заключается в том, чтобы найти букву, которая встречается в максимальном количестве слов
    //Значит нужно искать букву в найденом слове, а если бы мы хотели подсчитать количество букв, то
    //сначала проходили бы по слову, а потом уже по алфавиту.
    do {
        //Не нужно копировать подстроку в новую строчку.
        //Можно просто пройтись по исходной строке от pos до k.
        t = pos;
        for (; t < k; ++t) {
            if (str[t] == alphabet[j]) {
                //a[j] - количество слов, в которых содержится буква под индексом j
                a[j]++;
                //т.к. букву на позиции pos мы рассмотрели, то чтобы её каждый раз не проверять мы подвинемся влево.
                ++pos;
                //Т.к. все действия с буквой под индексом j мы произвели выше, то нет смысла проверять остальные буквы слова
                break;
            }
        }
        ++j;
    } while (j < size && t < pos); //если t == pos, то мы рассмотрели все слово
    k = str.find_first_of(razdel, ++pos); //Ищем конец следующего слова
}

int max = INT_MIN;
int m_index = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
    if (a[j] > max) {
        max = a[j];
        m_index = j;
    }
}

cout << "Буква " << alphabet[m_index] << " найдена в " << max << " словах!" << endl;
```

Если вы не будете дополнять `alphabet`, то можно было избавится от цикла, который пробегает по алфавиту, а использовать коды букв по ASCII таблице, что гораздо быстрее было бы.

Так же лично я бы вместо `find_first_of` и строки под разделители написал бы функцию типа `bool isRazdel(char symb) {...}`, но это опять токи, если вы не собираетесь дополнять список разделителей.

Все идеи, которые я предложил хоть и ускоряют работу, но делают алгоритм менее гибким под изменения. (списка букв, разделителей)

Comment: Спасибо большое